# Why i cant add new columns to my Users table?

Tags: sql-server

I am doing some homework. The users of my database uses some other attributes, not just the ones that ASP 2.0 automatically created for me when i implemented the login and registration mechanism. But when i try to save the modification displays me an error. Can someone give me a hand? 
This is the error:

[image]
The error says:

> 'aspnet_Users' table
>   - Unable to modify table.   ALTER TABLE only allows columns to be added
>   that can contain nulls, or have a
>   DEFAULT definition specified, or the
>   column being added is an identity or
>   timestamp column, or alternatively if
>   none of the previous conditions are
>   satisfied the table must be empty to
>   allow addition of this column. Column
>   'kjoptekvoten' cannot be added to
>   non-empty table 'aspnet_Users' because
>   it does not satisfy these conditions.

That database was automatically created when i implemented Forms based authentification and registration. The problem now is that that users needs some more attributes. How can i give to it more attributes? What is the easiest way to do it?Does not mind if it is not theorically correct(It is just for a homework).

I would appreciate a lot your help.

Comment: It especially matters that it is theoretically correct because it's homework :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apart form the technicalities on the database side, there is a deeper issue here.

You should not alter the aspnet_Users table because you are bypassing the way the membership 'system' in asp.net is working. Instead, have a look into the Profile mechanism: https://web.archive.org/web/20211020111657/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/101106-1.aspx

Comment: +1 use profiles or some other store depending on what you want to do. Don't muck with the internals though.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make the new attributes nullable or provide a default value. But you also need to consider how to obtain the values from db. The sql membership provider utilizes an auto generated stored procedure to put data into the membership user instance returned,so just adding the attributes in the table will not be sufficient to get the attribute values to your application.  I would use a user attribute table instead.

Comment: That does not seep to work(I just did that). See the updated image.
Could you please give me some guidelines or tips how to be able to create a user attribute table, and being able to add data? Please, i would appreciate a lot

Comment: Did you make it nullable, or did you provide a default value?

Comment: I just said (checkbox "Allow Nulls" not checked), that means it is nullable. But when i press Ctrl+S to save the changes, the error pops. How can i add a defauld value to a column i cannot create?

Comment: You can add a default value while creating the column. Under "Column Properties" you have the field "Default Value or Binding". 
But I think you really shouldn't add the field since is as mentioned will not be used. Consider using profiles instead.

Answer (score 3):

The error message says it all:
You are adding a new column that can't be Null (checkbox "Allow Nulls" not checked), but as you didn't provide a default value, it will be Null.
So SQL Server can't create the new column.

You can do two things:

a) Create the new column with Nulls allowed.
THEN put a default value in all existing rows:
`update aspnet_Users set kjoptekvoten = 0)`
...and THEN uncheck "Allow Nulls"

b) Create the new column directly with default values.
I don't know if you can do this in Management Studio, but it's easy in T-SQL:

```
alter table aspnet_Users 
add kjoptekvoten int not null
constraint Name_For_Constraint default(0) with values
```

This will add the new not nullable column, AND create a constraint with a default value, AND fill the default value in all existing rows (SQL Server will not do this without the "with values" clause).

Answer (score 2):

Normally I just set the column as allow nulls

then do an SQL UPDATE TABLE SET VALUE = whateva

then update the table definition to not allow nulls.